# Angular2 - md-slide-toggle displays the wrong value

Tags: javascript, html, angular, material-design, angular-material2

My problem is that the **md-slide-toggle** has the right value but it displays it wrong.

For example:

At the start the value is 1 and the toggle is active.

1. Time pressing the toggle: value is 0 but the toggle is still active.
2. Time pressing the toggle: value is 1 but now the toggle is now inactive.
3. ...

Check it out here: https://plnkr.co/edit/kxehpwaat5dezNActZbn?p=preview

//.html

```
<md-card>
  <md-slide-toggle ngDefaultControl (click)="onClick()"
     [ngModel]="(device)"></md-slide-toggle>
     {{device}}
</md-card>
```

//.ts

```
device:number = 1;

onClick() {
            let tmp;
            if (this.device == 1){
               tmp=0;
            }
            if (this.device == 0){
               tmp=1;
            }
            this.device=tmp;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're right, not having used the [Slide Toggle Component](https://material.angular.io/components/component/slide-toggle) before, it does seem like an odd behavior by default, although this seems to work:

Taken from your Plunker:

**Template**

```
<md-card>
     <md-slide-toggle 
      ngDefaultControl 
      (change)="onChange($event)" 
      [checked]="device"></md-slide-toggle>
     {{device}}
</md-card>
```

**TS**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'slide-toggle-overview-example',
  templateUrl: './slide-toggle-overview-example.html',
})
export class SlideToggleOverviewExample {

  device:number = 1;

  onChange(e: Event) {
        if (e.checked == true) {
          this.device = 1;
        } else {
          this.device = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

[Working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/COE2lLbG27eNGfXdBitG?p=preview)

At first, I thought it was your use of the `ngModel` binding *and* the `click` binding at the same time, but that wasn't the case (since I eventually noticed you were using one-way). It does seem that they get out of sync right from the start when you attempt to assign a numeric value instead of a `boolean`.

As this *does* work as expected as well:

**Template**

```
<md-card>
     <md-slide-toggle ngDefaultControl
     [(ngModel)]="device"></md-slide-toggle>
     {{device}}
</md-card>
```

**TS**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'slide-toggle-overview-example',
  templateUrl: './slide-toggle-overview-example.html',
})
export class SlideToggleOverviewExample {
  device:boolean = true;
}
```

Although, it appears that the ng team is aware of at least a version of this issue mentioned in the issue "[Slide toggle - (change) event will be fired even when the slider has not change.](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3526)"

Comment: In my case I can't use ngModel because I'm using a formControl, and this toggle is not part of the form's fields, it's just used to show more fields.

Answer (score 5):

You have to find the object property checked value from event . Working Code For Me

Template

```
<md-card>
     <md-slide-toggle 
      [(ngModel)]="device"
      (change)="onChange($event)"></md-slide-toggle>
     {{device}}
</md-card>
```

TS

```
 import {Component} from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
  selector: 'slide-toggle-overview-example',
  templateUrl: './slide-toggle-overview-example.html',
 })
 export class SlideToggleOverviewExample {

  device:number = 1;

  onChange(value) {
        if (value.checked == true) {
          this.device = 1;
          console.log(1);
        } else {
          this.device = 0;
          console.log(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with `setTimeout`;
In your html file, add an id to  `#contract`

```
<mat-slide-toggle color="primary" formControlName="contract" #contract>
  Contract
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

in your `.ts` file use

```
@ViewChild('contract') contract: MatSlideToggle;
```

before constructor;

and inside of `ngOnInit()`
add simple:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.contract.toggle();
});
```

it works for me

Answer (score 0):

In your Html

```
 <mat-slide-toggle [checked]="flags" (change)="flagsChange();" color="primary">
                            {{flags ? 'YES' : 'NO'}}</mat-slide-toggle>
```

in TS

```
  reimbursableChange() {
    if (!this.flags.reimbursable) {
      this.flags.reimbursable = true;
    } else {
      this.flags.reimbursable = false;
    }
  }
```